# Don't know where to start with these parameters

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm creating a custom module to help me write python faster with less code and cleaner syntax.

At the moment i am creating a function which is a cleaner version of wx.Accelerator.

By the end of this, i expect:

```
accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_CTRL,  ord('O'), PUT_ID_HERE),
                                 (wx.ACCEL_CTRL,  ord('S'), PUT_ID_HERE)])

self.SetAcceleratorTable(accel_tbl)
```

to become:

```
accelerate((wx.ACCEL_CTRL,'O',PUT_ID_HERE),
           (wx.ACCEL_CTRL,'S',PUT_ID_HERE))
```

The only problem is.. I dont know where to start.... I know how to process information through parameters, but i've never learnt how to process multiple tuples with dynamic information inside parameters.

Can someone provide insight? Thankyou.

**EDIT:**

Current code:

```
## Create a cleaner accelerator
def accelerate(*args):
    accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable(list(args))
    wx.SetAcceleratorTable(accel_tbl)
```

Current call:

```
import Sky

Sky.accelerate((wx.ACCEL_CTRL,'s',wx.ID_ANY),
               (wx.ACCEL_CTRL,'t',wx.ID_ANY))
```

Comment: ``self.SetAcceleratorTable(*accel_tbl)`` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method to your custom `wx.Window` class:

```
def accelerate(self,*args):
    accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable(args)
    self.SetAcceleratorTable(accel_tbl)
```

Then invoke it as follows:

```
win = YourCustomWindowClass(PUT_WINDOW_ARGUMENTS_HERE)
win.accelerate((wx.ACCEL_CTRL,'O',PUT_ID_HERE),(wx.ACCEL_CTRL,'S',PUT_ID_HERE))
```

Alternatively, you can define it as a function taking a `wx.Window` argument as follows:

```
def accelerate(win,*args):
    accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable(args)
    win.SetAcceleratorTable(accel_tbl)
```

The `*args` represents all the positional arguments as a tuple. If `AcceleratorTable` really requires a list, you can use `list(args)` instead as the argument (i.e. `accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable(list(args))`).

You can learn about `*args` [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls).

Comment: I referenced accelerate through an object and it didn't work.

var = Class()
var.accelerate(('','',''),
               ('','',''),
               ('','',''))

didnt quite work for me.

Comment: i have list(args) set.. then i call it by:

accelerate((wx.ACCEL_CTRL,'s',wx.ID_ANY))

But i get a type error.

TypeError: Expected a list object.

Comment: I have added my current code.. and current call for you to see in the edit.

traceback: http://pastebin.com/DeLrt7hP

Comment: ok i found where i went wrong, it was the ord()

thanks anyway :)